# error using "du" command

Tags: shell, filesystems, disk-usage, afs

I am on the university machine trying to estimate the disk usage I have on my space I do

```
du -csh ./
```

from the begining of my account, but an error is given that ./Yesterday/Yesterday is not a device, so I do

```
du -csh --exclude="Yes*" ./
```

and the error is stopped. But is there a more elegant way, and why is this error emerging? I can image how the Yesterday of Yesterday gets removed but whats the concepts behind the error.
Best,

1) **using stat:**

```
[ratz]s0128943: stat Yesterday 
File: `Yesterday' 
Size: 12288 Blocks: 24 IO Block: 4096 directory 
Device: 1dh/29d 
Inode: 714342402 
Links: 90 Access: (0745/drwxr--r-x) 
Uid: (35559/s0128943) 
Gid: (28065/ UNKNOWN) 
Access: 2010-10-15 13:06:07.000000000 +0100 
Modify: 2010-10-15 13:06:07.000000000 +0100 
Change: 2010-10-15 13:06:07.000000000 +0100
```

2) **using stat on Yesterday/Yesterday**

```
stat ./Yesterday/Yesterday 
stat: cannot stat `./Yesterday/Yesterday': No such device
```

3) **using uname for details**

```
[ratz]s0128943: uname -srv 
Linux 2.6.18-194.3.1.el5.inf.1 #1 SMP Fri May 21 12:59:58 BST 2010
```

4) **using df on Yesterday/**

```
[ratz]s0128943: df Yesterday/
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
AFS                    9000000         0   9000000   0% /afs
```

5) **using df on Yesterday/Yesterday**

```
df Yesterday/Yesterday 
df: `Yesterday/Yesterday': No such device
```

6) `mount | grep Yesterday` produces nothing

Comment: could you give us more information about /Yesterday/Yesterday ? IS this a regular folder or a symlink?

Comment: Looks like ./Yesterday is a snapshot of the whole home directory, which is usually a symlink.

Comment: Can you post the output of `stat Yesterday` and `stat Yesterday/Yesterday`?

Comment: Also, what OS is this (output of `uname -srv`), and what (if anything) is mounted on `Yesterday` (output of `df Yesterday/ Yesterday/Yesterday/` and `mount | grep Yesterday`)?

Comment: I suspect that the fact that your home directory is on AFS is relevant. For your `du` problem, try `du -x` (`du --one-file-system`). I'm not sure if it will work though; otherwise I can't think of anything better than `--exclude` like you already did.

Comment: could it be that this is a remote folder that should be mounted, but isn't?

Answer (score 3):

Your university seems to be using an AFS filesystem and the Yesterday folder contains a read-only snapshot of yesterday's content in the `Yesterday` folder. Probably the web page of your university's IT department has some information on this.

Probably you have a quota set for your disk space (i.e. a maximum amount you are allowed to use), you can check your current usage with:

```
fs lq
```